# WP_Query order by custom field, then randomly order some of results

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, sort

I'm not entirely sure how to word my question, but I'll give it a go.

Basically, what I'm wanting to do is order a group of posts by a custom field. I have a True/False custom field, created using the ACF plugin, which is displayed on a certain custom post type.

Right now, I've set up a query to firstly display posts with the True/False statement set to true, and then to display the posts with the statement set to false. This is working well.

What I want to do, however, is take the posts with the true statement and randomly change their order. All while keeping the current order or True first and then False in place.

Here is my current query.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// the query
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(
   array('post_type'=>'businesses', 
   'post_status'=>'publish', 
   'category_name'=>basename(get_permalink()), 
   'meta_key'=>'featured', 
   'orderby'=>'meta_value',
   'order'=>'DESC',
   'posts_per_page'=>20,
   'paged' => $paged)); ?>

<?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<!-- the loop -->
   <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: This is likely possible reasonably easily by tweaking the SQL in WP_Query to order by your meta_key then RAND(). But this means that the RAND() order will be applied to all the true items, and all the false items, I can't easily think of a way to do what you want _just_ to the true items. If that works for you I'll do a quick example of the code.

Comment: Hm, it looks like it might be possible with a funky ORDER BY CASE clause like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258376/mysql-conditional-order-by , but I'll wait to see if anyone has a better suggestion before trying this.

Comment: You could pull the IDs of the posts into two separate arrays, one that has the TRUE and another that has the FALSE.  Then run the output on each of those arrays and order them however you like.

Comment: @mozboz Would the RAND() randomise the order of all the items, or would it keep the True posts first and just shuffle most sets of items? If so that could possibly be a fix.

Comment: @TonyDjukic Any chance you could give me an example of how this would be done?

Comment: I'll try to get a sample up as quickly as possible; I'm just in the midst of some work and a deadline.

Comment: @TonyDjukic Thanks. No rush either.